# Normed space in finite dimensional subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Would appreciate some explicit solution to the following question as I already have the solution but I am not quite clear:

a. Show that a normed space X is separable if and only if there are finite dimensional subspaces $ X_1 \subset X_2 \subset ...$ of $X$ such that:
$\bar\cup_{n\in N} X_n = X$.

b. I also need to find a concrete example of a separable normed space $X$ and finite dimensional spaces $X_1 \subset X_2 \subset ...$ of $X$ such that: $\bar\cup_{n\in N} X_n = X$ but $\cup_{n\in N} X_n \neq  X$.

I know the following proposition: Let $X$ be a normed space,  and $(x_n)_{n \in N}$ a sequence in X with X ={$\overline{span \{x_n: n \in N\}}$}. Then $X$ is separable.

Comment: Close votes are already flowing (I am not a close voter). Maybe add some details or an attempted solution to prevent your question from being put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{\{x_{n}: n=1,2,...\}}=X$ and $X_{n}=\left<x_{1},...,x_{n}\right>$, then $\overline{\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}X_{n}}=X$.

For an example, look up any separable Hilbert space $X$ and let $\mathcal{B}=\{x_{n}: n=1,2,...\}$ be its Hilbert basis, then with those $X_{n}$ defined, the union is not the whole $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do I show the RHS of the implication meaning that $X$ is separable?

Comment: Each $X_{n}$ is separable, then take its dense subset $B_{n}$ and the union of all those $B_{n}$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: Another example: polynomials of degree at most $n$ form a subspace of $C[0,1]$ whose union over $n$ is not equal to $C[0,1]$.